# How to define an html element to have a polygon shape, and how to change the shape with animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create this button in html with a little animation as below.

How can I make the below polygon shape in css, and how to move it to a regular rectangle in animation on hover?

**This is what I am trying to make it look like:**

[image]

**And here is how it should look like on hover:**

[image]

Thanks for any help

Comment: Show what you've tried already. Check this in the meanwhile: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/animation/

Comment: nothing have worked i can't code css to achieve this XD

Comment: `i can't code css` - and why is it?

Comment: You say you have tried...show us **that**.

Comment: I'm going to vote to reopen this because this is not a simple "homework" problem. Animating HTML/CSS is a fairly advanced topic and one that even accomplished programmers will struggle with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit messy, but it is what I get so far:

```css
body {
background-color: #FFB504;
}
.cta {
  color: white;
  border: none;
  width: 240px;
  height: 80px;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  position:relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
}
.cta-content {
padding-right: 20px;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  z-index:1;
}

.cta:before {
 clip-path: polygon(10px 10px, 230px 10px, 190px 70px, 10px 70px);
  transition: all .3s ease;
  will-change: clip-path;
    background-color: #0081B1;

}
.cta-border, .cta-border:before, .cta-border:after, .cta:before {
content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all .3s ease;
 }
 .cta-border{
 overflow: hidden;
 }
.cta-border:before {
  
   clip-path: polygon(0px 0px, 220px 0px, 170px 80px, 0px 80px);
   border: 2px solid white;

}
.cta-border:after {
transform-origin: center center;
transform: translate(-28px, -69px) rotate(32deg);
border-right: 2px solid white;
height: 94.34px;
}
.cta:hover .cta-content {
padding-right: 0;
}
.cta:hover:before, .cta:hover .cta-border:before {
clip-path: polygon( 0px 0px, 240px 0px, 240px 80px, 0px 80px);
}

.cta:hover .cta-border:after {
  transform: translate(0,0) rotate(0);
}
```

```html
<button class="cta">
<span class="cta-content">HIRE ME</span>
<span class="cta-border"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: This answer could really be improved by explaining the different parts or at least grouping the css into sections according to its purpose. This is an advanced feature of HTML, and a good answer here could be useful.